# Copy direct link to Excel document

Tags: document-library, office-web-apps

I want to send a link to a document that fails in Office Web App. How can I easily copy a direct link to an excel document, to be opened directly by the excel desktop application?

Answer (score 1):

Send to -> "Email a link" gives me the correct link.